# Show contextMenu on datatable left click and right click

Tags: primefaces

In the showcase of [datatable contextmenu](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/contextMenu.xhtml)
the `contextMenu` is working as normal, it shows on right click of a row, and I was wondering if it's possible to show the `contextMenu` on row select (left click) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the type of the `event` on the `contextMenu`.

In your case the left click is a normal `click` event, and if you want to keep the right click also add `contextmenu` to the event list:

```xhtml
<p:contextMenu for="tableId" event="click contextmenu">
   <p:menuitem value="View" />
</p:contextMenu>
```

Comment: this makes it works only with left click, but i want it to work with both left click and right click.

Comment: please update your question with this requirement, your question is clearly asking for a left click only

Comment: I have updated the answer, now it works on both cases